# Unable to import external RSS feed to site

Tags: views, feeds, entities

I want to add a vertically scrolling ticker which is fed content via an external RSS feed.

```
* Modules being used: Views, Feed, CTools, Job Scheduler

* Issue 1
```

I tried setting up a static RSS feed block using Feed Module. I followed many tutorials but in the end all I could do is created 100s of content pages when importing data from feed. But I could never get a consolidated page/block where I could see the list. I created views with Page/Block/Feed but I couldn't find how to link the feed with the view.

```
* Issue 2
```

When I use the Feed Module and map the Feed, I get following errors:

```
•   Notice: Undefined index: 0 in user_node_load() (line 3605 of modules/user/user.module).
•   Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in user_node_load() (line 3605 of modules/user/user.module).
•   Notice: Undefined index: 0 in user_node_load() (line 3606 of modules/user/user.module).
•   Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in user_node_load() (line 3606 of modules/user/user.module).
•   Notice: Undefined index: 0 in user_node_load() (line 3604 of modules/user/user.module).
•   Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in user_node_load() (line 3604 of modules/user/user.module).
```

I have no clue why this error is coming up. I tried looking for existing drupal issues, but found live sites with such errors instead.

```
* Issue 3
```

I want to populate ticker with RSS content with the RSS data.

If anyone has a tried and tested link which guides step by step for importing external RSS feed for Drupal 7 (I found too many links but mostly for drupal 6), I'll be really grateful. Also, please let me know if there is any other way to do it besides Feed module [I'm using aggregrator but I want content to be created for each RSS feed entity].

Also, if ticker module allows to use RSS feed any guidance will be really appreciated.

'Note: Tried https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/21719/how-to-display-external-rss-using-feeds-module-and-views. I don't have content type Feed. Am I missing modules?'

Comment: Answer to the errors : check http://drupal.org/node/1067076 and create a user with uid 0.

Answer (score 0):

Using Feeds.
You create a feed importer with RSS syndication import (common syndication parser).
if there is only one feed, in basic you don't need to attach to content type (use standalone form) and set the periodic import time.
Node processor attach to bundle type (your content type to receive the nodes.
Then map the feed fields to your content fields.
Finally navigate to /import to see feeds listed and add the url.
Nodes can be listed in views normally (from your content type - the bundle), I scroll them using views ticker